# Is this "month" a noun adjective?

Tags: word-usage

Thank you in advance,

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/labour-party-says-johnson-cant-124214555.html), 6th passage says,

> Parliament has already dealt Johnson a series of setbacks and derailed his promise to take Britain out of the EU by the end of **the month** "come what may." Johnson has now pinned his hopes on an early general election, calling for one on Dec. 12, but how Britain will solve its Brexit stalemate is still completely up in the air.

Is this bold line "the month" the noun adjective modifying the "come what may"?

It sounds a bit odd to me personally when I read the preceding sentence as a whole.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, "the month" does not modify "come what may."

**[Come what may](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+what+may)** is a set phrase meaning "**regardless of the consequences**" or "**no matter what happens**" and it functions as an adverbial phrase modifying the verb of the sentence/clause. In this case, it modifies "take... out."

"...by the end of the month" is another adverbial phrase modifying "take... out."

Comment: +1: Though as a nitpick, potentially "come what may" could be actually modifying "by the end of the month" instead, though in light of Johnson's political stance, the intended meaning is probably "both".